# Problems using JSTL to print a Java List

Tags: java, jsp, maven, servlets, foreach

I am trying to print a Java list using c:forEach, I have an idea how to print the list in jsp. However, I am getting the error "Unknown tag c:forEach". I have been reading that can be due to dependencies en Maven, so I included the dependency. After, I read that only versions above 2.5 are allowed to use this feature, so I check the version:

```
Servlet version: 3.0
JSP version: 2.2
Java version: 1.8.0_25
```

I don't know what else to check, because I continue having this problem. Below I included my pom file and the source code using c:forEach. Maybe something else is bothering.

pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>RESTful</groupId>
    <artifactId>clientLibrary</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>clientLibrary</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>clientLibrary</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
            <!-- artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId -->
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
            <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.0</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
            <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
            <version>3.7.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.sun.jersey</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
            <version>1.8</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.1</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
            <version>1.2</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.16</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

Servlet (deletePolicy.java):

```
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter printWriter = response.getWriter();

        Client client= Client.create();
        WebResource webResource= client.resource("http://localhost:8080/clientLibrary/webapi/policy");

        //create an object of RequestDispatcher 
        RequestDispatcher rd = request.getRequestDispatcher("GetPolicy"); 

        // send the client data available with req of delete to req of getPolicy with include() 
        rd.include(request, response);

        List<Policy> policies = (List<Policy>) request.getAttribute("policies");

        printWriter.print("List of books in Delete: ");

        for(Policy policy : policies) {
             printWriter.println("<li>"+"ID: "+policy.getId()+"<br>"+"Max Number of Books: "+policy.getMax_books()+"<br>"+"Year of Book: "+policy.getYear_book()+"<br>"+"Activated: "+policy.getActivate()+"<br></li><br>");
         }

        //Show to the user the possible options to delete using radio button
        request.setAttribute("policies", policies);

        RequestDispatcher rd2 = getServletConfig().getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/showRecordsToDelete.jsp");
        rd2.include(request,response);


        //Receive the answer
        printWriter.print("I am comming back from showRecordsToDelete.jsp");


        /*ClientResponse rs=webResource.accept(
                   MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_TYPE,
                   MediaType.APPLICATION_XML_TYPE).
                   delete(ClientResponse.class,input);

        printWriter.print("Delete a policy");*/
    }
```

showRecordsToDelete.jsp:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Current Records:</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Select a policy to be deleted:</h2>
    <table>
        <%-- JSTL foreach to loop a list retrieve from a servlet(DeletePolicy.java) in jsp --%>
        <c:forEach items="${policies}" var="policies">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${policies.id}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${policies.max_books}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${policies.year_book}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${policies.activate}" /></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
</table>
    <p>I will show the records</p>
</body>
</html>
```

My idea is to show the list of records and use a radio button to select the record and return the information to the servlet. However, when trying to print the list, I am having problems with unknown tag c:forEach.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Cheers

Comment: Don't use the same variable name for the current policy and the list of policies. And declare the JSTL library with a `<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>` directive at the top of your JSP. Read http://stackoverflow.com/tags/jstl/info

Comment: I got the error "Can not find the tag library descriptor for “http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core”, so I changed to this:
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%> ,but didn't work either.  I updated my dependency in pom.xml instead of 1.2 , I changed to 1.2.1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Include the taglibe in your jsp with the next line and It is going to solve your problem :

```
<%@ taglib prefix="c" 
           uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" %>
```

Check the next link for more information http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jsp/jsp_standard_tag_library.htm

**---Edits-----**

use this dependency

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>jstl</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

instead of this

```
<dependency>
   <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl</groupId>
   <artifactId>jstl-api</artifactId>
   <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I don't know why I am getting an error in taglib.  Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" , so I changed to 
<%@taglib uri="java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"; prefix="c"%>, but I got the same error :(

Comment: Add the dependency & rebuild & refresh the project

Answer (score 1):

In your jsp you need to include the jstl tag

```
    <%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
        pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
    <%@taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"/>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
    <title>Current Records:</title>
```

Also in you c:forEach user different variable name for iterating

```
         <c:forEach items="${policies}" var="policy">
            <tr>
                <td><c:out value="${policy.id}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${policy.max_books}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${policy.year_book}" /></td>
                <td><c:out value="${policy.activate}" /></td>
            </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

Also as per your comment try adding the maven dependency in your pom

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    <version>1.2</version>
</dependency>
```